# Click event not fired, but mouseover working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue JS for my project and find some stumbling block.

I've used:

```
<input v-model="spam" @keyup="spamegg=true;" @blur="spamegg=false;" />
<div v-if="spamegg" class="someclass">
    <a v-for="str in arr" @click.prevent="foobar(); barbaz();" href="#">{{ str }}</a>
</div>
```

but the `click` event is not being fired.

My `foobar` method contains:

```
foobar: function() {
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

Same goes for `barbaz` function.

Interesting thing is i've checked with `@mouseover` event and its working properly.

FWIW, the `div` is actually a dropdown as far as CSS is concerned.

Please let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: try prevent="foobar" (it's been a while with Vue but I think you give the function, not the result)

Comment: The semicolon can often cause issues in `@click` attributes

Comment: @Devilscomrade Thanks. But the same is working for `@mouseover`.

Comment: @Djave I've tried without the semicolon, no luck!

Comment: Could this be because you're hiding the spamegg div when the input loses focus? Trying to click on the links would blur the input and make the links disappear, possibly before the click can fully register. Try getting rid of the blur temporarily

Comment: At initial rendering, the element has `Display:none;` or is absent?

Comment: I checked it in codepen and there is no problem. Just removed `()` at the end of `foobar()` function. Your console shows any errors?

Comment: i'm trying out your example and it works fine , i think you're getting some errors that prevent the normal execution

Comment: @obermillerk Thats it! Thanks so much! Please add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep,so I tried your example in jsfiddle and first of all there's a typo in the `@blur` handler, you put `spmaegg` instead of `spamegg`. However, even with this fixed the click events don't register properly. Removing the blur event allows them to register properly. I think this is because the blur happens on mousedown but the click event doesn't get fired until after mouseup, so the div containing the links actually disappears before you fully click. Seems like you need a new mechanism for your dropdown unfortunately, maybe some container around the input element and link list that listens for the blur event, that way clicking in the link list won't blur the container and it will stay open.

For reference, here's my fiddle with the blur handling removed and you can see that the console output fires properly: https://jsfiddle.net/L1khuca2/

Comment: Fixed the typo :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to implement some kind of dropdown, i suggest to hide the div after clicking on a link and adding the link text value to the input, and you should to remove the `@blur` event :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    spam: '',
    spamegg: false,
    arr: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
  },
  methods: {
    foobar: function(str) {
      console.log('clicked');
      this.spam = str;
      // this.spamegg = false;
    },
    barbaz() {
      console.log('bar');
    }
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column
}

#app {
  background: #725585;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px
}

.someclass {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

a {}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Vue.delete">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" @click.stop="spamegg = false;">
    <input v-model="spam" @keyup="spamegg=true;" />

    <div v-if="spamegg" class="someclass">
      <a v-for="str in arr" @click.prevent="foobar(str); barbaz();" href="#">{{ str }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks and upvoted. But actually I want to hide the dropdown when users e.g. clicks anyplace other than the input and dropdown. Any idea?

Comment: @Uyerm i added `@click.stop="spamegg = false;"` in the root element `.stop` to prevent event propagation to children elements